# Scribe Java POST follow request to Twitter v2 API fail with Unautorized 401

Tags: java, api-authorization

I am trying to use Scribe library to send API calls to Twitter v2 API with OAuth1 authentication. I manage to send GET users/me request successfully, but its fail on POST follow request.

```
public boolean followUser(String accountId, String userId) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    OAuth1AccessToken twitterUserAccessToken = getTwitterUserAccessToken();

    request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, BASE_URL + "/users/" + accountId + "/following");
    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.addBodyParameter("target_user_id", userId);

    service.signRequest(twitterUserAccessToken, request);
    com.github.scribejava.core.model.Response response = service.execute(request);
    System.out.println(response.getBody());

    return response.isSuccessful();
}
```

This request fail with Status Code 401 Unauthorized

```
{
  "title": "Unauthorized",
  "type": "about:blank",
  "status": 401,
  "detail": "Unauthorized"
}
```

Everything is working, fine for GET users/me request which use the same authentication method OAuth1

```
public boolean userMe() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    OAuth1AccessToken twitterUserAccessToken = getTwitterUserAccessToken();
    request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, BASE_URL + "/users/me");
    service.signRequest(twitterUserAccessToken, request);
    com.github.scribejava.core.model.Response response = service.execute(request);
    
    return response.isSuccessful();
}
```

Can anybody familiar with Scribe give answer to this issue I also try to use RestAssured but the result is same even for GET users/me request.